# Why cache the GameObject is faster?

Tags: unity-game-engine

```
private GameObject mGo;

void Start()
{
    this.mGo = this.gameObject;
}


void OnGUI()
{
    if (GUILayout.Button("T1"))
    {
        float time = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
        int s = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            s = this.gameObject.layer;
        }

        Debug.Log("T1：" + (Time.realtimeSinceStartup - time));
    }

    if (GUILayout.Button("T2"))
    {
        float time = Time.realtimeSinceStartup;
        int s = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100000; i++)
        {
            s = this.mGo.layer;
        }
        Debug.Log("T2：" + (Time.realtimeSinceStartup - time));
    }
}
```

This is a simple Demo.
I'm reading other source code,then find this.
I want to know why T1 and T2 are different?
Someone could tell me why.

Comment: That's a bad bad benchmark, it's not reliable. Anyway, the property might have side effects.

Comment: As a side note, you should not be using `OnGUI` for development in games. That function should only be used if you are designing a control for the editor.

Answer (score 3):

this.gameObject is a property

```
   public GameObject gameObject { get;}
```

so it is a method and methods are added a bit of overhead in their usage. 
First the program needs to store the current index, then jump to the method location, pile the parameter on the stack and run the code in the method. Then it does the invert effect of returning to the program where it left off.

On top of that there may be some extra check in the property.

Using a cache version means you are using a reference that is accessed directly.